# How to disable some checkboxes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, checkbox

I am trying to iterate over a field that has some checkboxes in it and disable some checkboxes based on data in an array.

For each of the boxes I want to check if the value of a checkbox is found in an array that is a variable from php. If yes, the checkbox is disabled and a class is added to parent.

Why doesn't this code work?
This is the first function I have ever written all by myself in jQuery so have mercy.

```
jQuery(function($) { // wordpress no-conflict hack

    var booked = php echo $booked_24; // the php echo syntax is wrong here, 
                but the editor does not allow me to put in proper php tags.

    $('div#acf-booking_times_24 input:checkbox').each(function() {
        if ($.inArray(this.value, booked) !== -1) {
            $(this).attr('disabled',true);
            $(this).parent('label').addClass('unavailable');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Use .prop() instead of .attr()

Comment: in debuger check is it enter into "if" statement

Answer (score 0):

Try Replacing The Below Code Snippet
Replace Your

```
  $(this).attr('disabled',true);
```

by

```
$(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: No it works Different(for some Browsers) if You are Using Prop in place of attr then use 
'disabled',true else for attr 'disabled','disabled'

or try running in other Browser

Comment: attr('disabled', true) works if I target the entire div without the iteration, so problem is somewhere in the if statement, I think.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the mistake, it was painfully simple.

```
if ($.inArray($(this).value, booked) !== -1)
```

should be

```
 if ($.inArray($(this).val(), booked) !== -1)
```

Thanks Nicolai for the fiddle, it helped me to find it.